# SharePoint 2013 Permission

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new with sharepoint. I want to create a document library( e.g FinanceDocs) in sharepoint 2013 and  want to allow FinanceGroupUser to view, edit, etc. But, I don't to allow other user to view, except Full Control users. I set permission for that library. But, It is not working as I intended. Limited Access user out of FinanceGroup can view that library. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've set it up correctly.

One way to check is to have a test user with similar permissions to the restricted users and see if that functions as you want.

Have a look at this blog to understand Limited Access:
http://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-are-sharepoint-limited-access

Answer (score 0):

`Site Contents - > Add an App -> New Document Library` (To Create a Library)

You can set the permission levels according to the Group of Users from the Active Directory .

`Library Settings - > Permissions for this Library -> Add the User & Set the Permission` .